# Can I be notified when "merge conflict" appears on my change?

Tags: gerrit

Let assume that I have several changes in review state in Gerrit.
Can I be notified (via email) when "merge conflict" appears on one of my changes?

Have a nice day,
Adam

Answer (score 1):

You can't receive this information by e-mail (unless you wrote a script to automate this task using REST) but you have other good options:

- Search field

You can use the **Search** feature to search for the following:

```
owner:username AND status:open AND NOT is:mergeable
```

This will show your open changes with conflicts.

- My Menu

You can add a menu entry for the search showed above at **Settings** > **Preferences** > **My Menu** adding the following URL:

```
#/q/owner:username+AND+status:open+AND+NOT+is:mergeable
```

Comment: Great. Thank you.

btw:
I think that "not" should be uppercase :)

`owner:username AND status:open AND NOT is:mergeable`

Comment: Yes, it has. I just fixed.